# ввод и вывод python

Tags: python-3.x

Напишите программу, которая по данному числу N от 1 до 9 выводит на экран N пингвинов. Изображение одного пингвина имеет размер 5×9 символов, между двумя соседними пингвинами также имеется пустой (из пробелов) столбец. Разрешается вывести пустой столбец после последнего пингвина. Для упрощения рисования скопируйте пингвина из примера в среду разработки.

данный код не проходит проверку онлайн системы, в чем ошибка?

```
a = '   _~_    '
b = '  (o o)   '
c = ' /  V  \\  '
d = '/(  _  )\\ '
e = '  ^^ ^^   '
request = int(input("Enter number 1-9:"))
print(request * a, sep=' ')
print(request * b, sep=' ')
print(request * c, sep=' ')
print(request * d, sep=' ')
print(request * e, sep=' ')
```

Comment: Не указано, какая именно онлайн система имеется в в виду. Ошибка может быть вызвана тем, что у них используется python 2.x, а не python 3. Пробовали добавить `from __future__ import print_function` ?

Comment: Возможно, проблема в наличии строчки `"Enter number 1-9:"`

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, я никогда раньше не писал на питоне и это моя первая программа! :]

Просто решил немного оптимизировать ваш код. Может к этому валидатор и придирается?

```
peng = [
  '   _~_    ',
  '  (o o)   ',
  ' /  V  \\  ',
  '/(  _  )\\ ',
  '  ^^ ^^   '
]

request = int(input("Enter number 1-9:"))
for i in peng: print(request * i, sep=' ')
```